# how to load data before controller load?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

How to get data from service before loading the view and controller. I do like that

```
resolve: {
            getAlbum: function(albumService){
                return albumService.getAlbums();

        },getAtum: function(albumService){
                return albumService.getAtum();

        }

    }
```

I have one service this

```
.factory('albumService', ['$http', '$q'],
    function albumService($http, $q) {
        // interface
        var service = {
            albums: [],
            getAlbums: getAlbums,
            getAtum:getAtum
        };
        return service;

        // implementation
        function getAlbums() {
            var def = $q.defer();

            $http.get("data.json")
                .success(function(data) {
                    service.albums = data;
                    def.resolve(data);
                })
                .error(function() {
                    def.reject("Failed to get albums");
                });
            return def.promise;
        }

             function getAtum() {
            var def = $q.defer();

            $http.get("data.json")
                .success(function(data) {
                    service.albums = data;
                    def.resolve(data);
                })
                .error(function() {
                    def.reject("Failed to get albums");
                });
            return def.promise;
        }
    })
```

I need to get data from service before loading this controller and view .

```
.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.playlists = [{
    title: 'Reggae',
    id: 1
  }, {
    title: 'Chill',
    id: 2
  }, {
    title: 'Dubstep',
    id: 3
  }, {
    title: 'Indie',
    id: 4
  }, {
    title: 'Rap',
    id: 5
  }, {
    title: 'Cowbell',
    id: 6
  }];
})
```

I am getting data from two service .I need to show loader till I get data from both service.I am using this to show loader

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicLoading/

Plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/4k7fliaYQx3teVH326cD?p=info

Comment: The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: please provide plunker

Comment: Your plunker is missing a valid reference to cordova.js

Answer (score 4):

The `resolve` properties are injected automatically by `ui-router` right after they get resolved.

```
.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function(getAlbum, getAtum) {
    // getAlbum and getAtum are resolved and ready to use
})
```

1. I would use `albums` and `atum` instead of `getAlbum` and `getAtum` as it is the data itself.
2. You use `defer` wrongly. `$http.get` is a promise itself. also, `success` and `error` are deprecated, use `then` instead.

   return $http.get().then();

Simplest [jsbin](https://output.jsbin.com/xuwimoyoga/edit).

Comment: please tell how to use resolve instead of using in controller

Comment: The injected "things" are coming from the `resolve` are the data itself. that why I suggested you to rename it.

Comment: coluld you change my plunker ..provide the best way to do that ?..please provide plunker

Comment: please provide plunker

Comment: @user944514. Roy provided you with the correct answer. The controller and the view will not be loaded until getAlbum and getAtum are resolved. I am sure that Roy would provide you with a plunker if yours was working in the first place. Look in the console and you'll find missing references.

Comment: @zszep good point. Anyway, I edited my post with a simple example (not using `ionic` but it doesn't matter).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show loading spinner on page until its resolve. you can do something like below.

```
  resolve: {
        apiData: "albumService",
        itemDetailsData: function($q, apiData) {
          console.log("Spinner on :")
          var item = apiData.getAlbums();
          if (item) {
            console.log("Spinner Off :")
            return $q.when(item);
          } else {
            return $q.reject();
          }
        }
      }
```

In your controller you can inject `itemDetailsData` as a dependency.

Hope this helps

Comment: could you please give plunker

Comment: @user944513 Please check this update Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/iY0sCnM5dzvassz2k0KL?p=preview